# Continue statement in python does not work

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, while-loop, continue

```
i=0
while i<10:
    if i==2:
        continue    
    print(i)
    i+=1
```

**#0
#1
#This is the output i get**
The code stops at 1 and does not execute further

Comment: so.... `continue` works perfectly? [ask]

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what your code is trying to do, but the reason it produces an infinite loop is that you don't update `i` before continuing.

Try tracing your code. 0 and 1 print fine. Then you hit 2, and you immediately continue back to the top of the loop, and so forth.

Comment: The important point is that `continue` causes it to skip `i+=1`.